# Creating image which sweeps across the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a banner that sweeps across the current scene. I want to create a banner which sweeps down the screen to show the current round. My attempt at it is creating a UIImageView and add it to the current view. However, i assume its calling the didMoveToView Function and resetting everything in that scene, which is something i dont want it to do. Here is my attempt:

```
-(void)createBanner{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Banner"]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    CABasicAnimation *sweep = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    sweep.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
    sweep.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, self.frame.size.height)];
    sweep.duration = 10;
    sweep.additive = YES;
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:sweep forKey:@"sweep"];

}
```

EDIT: i am using sprite kit in order to create the game.

Comment: are you actually making a  Sprite Kit project as your tag suggests?  If so, then you shouldn't be using UIKit to do any of this.

Comment: You're using `self.view` as the superview and `self.frame` as your end position. You might want to change it to `self.view.frame`.

Comment: @hamobi yes I am using sprite kit in order to do this.  I felt that it wasn't the right way to do this. What are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hamobi said, it's best to use an 'SKSpriteNode' in Sprite Kit and not UIKit. Assuming your'e adding to an 'SKScene', your code above translated to Sprite Kit is:

```
-(void)createBanner{
    SKSpriteNode* spriteNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Banner"]
    //It's good practice not to resize the sprite in code as it should already be the right size but...
    spriteNode.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)
    //Set its center off to the left of the screen for horizontal sweep, or you can do vertical and set it off the top of the screen...
    spriteNode.postion = CGPointMake(-spriteNode.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(spriteNode)

    //Then to sweep from left to right...
    SKAction* sweep = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(spriteNode.size.width/2, self.size.height/2) duration:10]
    spriteNode.runAction(sweep)
}
```

I think that covers most of it.